# Why can't users be added to the list at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

There is a queue to which users can be added, in Firebase Cloud Firestore it looks like this:

```
Collection(users) => document(users) => field(queue[arr])
```

[image]

To distinguish users, an id is used, which is stored in localStorage, but when users try to log in at the same time, only one of them logs in.
Here's the code:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchQueue = async () => {
            const db = getFirestore();
            const usersRef = doc(db, "autocommitQueue", "users");

            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(usersRef, (doc) => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    setUsers(doc.data().queue || []);
                }
            });

            return () => unsubscribe();
        };

        fetchQueue();
    }, []);

    const setFirebase = async (arr) => {
        const refDb = doc(getFirestore(), "autocommitQueue", "users");

        await setDoc(refDb, {
            queue: arr,
        });
    };

    const addUser = () => {
        const id = uuid4();
        if (name.length > 0) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("id") === null) {
                if (!users) {
                    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
                    setFirebase([{ name: name, id: id }])                                  
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem("id", id);

                    setFirebase([...users, { name: name, id: id }])                     
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return(
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        display:
                            localStorage.getItem("id") !== null
                                ? "none"
                                : "flex",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    <TextField
                        type={"text"}
                        id="outlined-number"
                        label={"Name"}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            setName(event.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button
                        onClick={addUser}
                        variant={"outlined"}
                        sx={{ "&.MuiButton-root": { height: "56px" } }}
                    >
                        Push
                    </Button>
                </Box>
    )
```

I tried adding through transactions, but the bug still remained.

Comment: You have an issue around your persistent user managment in any case.   `useState([])` is initializing to an empty state and because of the `if (!users)` you are treating the react state `users` as your source of truth which can get out of sync with the local store.  I'd add a `useEffect` to set those on component initialization and prevent `addUser` until it completes.  Implementing a redux store across the app can help alleviate this juggling

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the cause of the bug is based on your description. But to add a user to the `queue` field, I'd recommend [using the `array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array). That operator allows you to just send the new user ID to the database, which then executes is atomically.

Comment: I apologize for the inaccurate description, the error is that in one second a request to be added to the queue is received from different devices, then only one is added, I understand that this is due to the fact that several users are interacting simultaneously with one array, this error only occurs when users are added in one second.

Comment: Did you try the solution in my answer?